# what is "SI0CSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted"?

Tags: linux, command-line

Im a lubuntu 20.04 user, and I'm trying to change my mac adress. I'm following a tutorial on linux hint since I don't really know anything and I entered the command "ifconfig enp0s31f6 down" to turn my network card down.

```
example@file:~$ ifconfig enp0s31f6 down
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it or what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: since I don't really know anything  .......  You rarely need to change network device MAC addresses.  I suggest leaving the MAC the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

This requires roots privs and cannot be changed by an ordinary user.

Try `sudo ifconfig enp0s31f6 down`

Comment: Ok thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had same error running Metasploit in Kali. Issue was that I was logged in as the kali user and this user didn't have permissions. Once I switched to root `$ sudo su` and then ran Metasploit `# msfconsole`, I didn't get SIOCSIFFLAGS error anymore.